# Is there any categorization of cognitive abilities based on brain structure and biology?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, reference-request, cognitive-modeling

I'm pretty sure that the answer to the following question is yes :
Is there any categorization of cognitive abilities based on brain structure and biology?

However, because I'm a newbie, I'm kind of lost in the subject of neuroscience, I would like to know where I could find such a thing.

Here's what I call "a categorization based on brain structure and biology":
From what I read on the subject (a French book called "Apprendre" (= "To learn") from Stanislas Dehaene - [English translation of synopsis](https://translate.google.com/translate?oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-m&client=ob&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&sl=fr&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.co.uk%2FApprendre-talents-cerveau-d%25C3%25A9fi-machines%2Fdp%2F2738145426)), some brain areas that seem to have been designed for some "primitive" tasks (I have in mind a study showing that the area that is usually active in face recognition seems to be reused for the ability to read for modern sapiens).
So, I suppose that this area has some information processing abilities that can be explained in a certain way by biology/brain structure, etc... So, we might relate "face recognition" and "reading" in the same category of cognitive ability.

To summarise, what I'd like to know for a certain cognitive ability:

- Which part of the brain is concerned?
- If possible, why is it this part? (the structure, the biology of it etc...)
- What is the fundamental use of this part?
- How is this ability working?

(if it's something about being able to do some maths, how do we do it, which part of the brain and why, what should this part of the brain be used for, how do we make abstract thoughts and how do we resolve an equation)

Can you please point me in the direction of some references where I can learn the state of the art on the subject? (more especially in the field of intellectual abilities, memory, and learning).

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. You said *"From what I read on the subject..."* What was it you read? Can you please site the author and title of books or articles you read?

Comment: Also asking for *good* references leads to opinion-based answers which is off-topic here. I have edited your question to make the question fit your needs and be non opinion-based.

Comment: Can you be more specific of what you need to know? Categorization based on brain structure and biology of  intellectual abilities, memory, and learning is kind of vague. You want to know which brain areas these abilities are situated?

Comment: I tried to be more specific this time. Hope it is clear enough.

Comment: Thanks for the edits - this seems super super broad. It might be better to start with a cognitive neuroscience textbook.

Comment: You can chose a cognitive function, such as memory, and search for: memory + brain structure. This way you'll get a brain map of cognitive functions - you can also search for that.